# React Parsing string as html and applying a function to DOM with forwardRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-forwardref

On a ReactJs project I try to parse with `com.wiris.js.JsPluginViewer.parseElement(ref, true, function () {});` function.

According to the docs, that function is to be applied to specific elements on the DOM. In the samples with pure javascript, they first set innerHTML of dom element and then apply the function.

So I thought that it would be handled using refs in React. (not sure if its the best way)

I have an array which includes some string to be rendered as html. I took all refs as an array with `useRef([])` and then set each element's ref using `refs.current[index]`

According to the type I directly render string with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or use a wrapper component to render with a child component on which I would use that special function.

But I couldn't reach innerHTML property of the ref before applying the function in the WirisWrapper. I tried `ref.innerHTML`  and `ref.current.innerHTML`

**Parser as Parent**

```
import { useRef, createRef } from 'react';
import WirisWrapper from './WirisWrapper';

const Parser = ({ itemsArray }) => {
    let refs = useRef([]);

    refs.current = itemsArray.map((ref, index) => (refs.current[index] = createRef()));

    return (
        <div>
            {itemsArray.map((item, index) =>
                item.type === 'math' ? (
                    <WirisWrapper
                        ref={el => (refs.current[index] = el)}
                        key={index}
                        mString={item.html}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <div key={index} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.html}}>
                    </div>
                )
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Parser;
```

**WirisWrapper as Child**

```
import { forwardRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const WirisWrapper = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const { mString } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current && com.wiris.js.JsPluginViewer) {
            ref.current.innerHTML = mString;
            com.wiris.js.JsPluginViewer.parseElement(ref, true, function () {});
        }
    }, [ref, com.wiris.js.JsPluginViewer]);

    return <div ref={ref}></div>;
});

export default WirisWrapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

`refs.current = itemsArray.map((ref, index) => (refs.current[index] = createRef()));` looks to be creating a new React ref each render cycle ***and*** mutating the existing array at the same time.

You want to only create React refs if they don't previously exist. Map the `itemsArray` array to a new array each render, returning existing refs or creating new refs.

```
refs.current = itemsArray.map((ref, i) => refs.current[index] ?? createRef()));
```

Then just access the ref by index when mapping the UI.

```
{itemsArray.map((item, index) =>
  item.type === 'math' ? (
    <WirisWrapper
      ref={refs.current[index]}
      key={index}
      mString={item.html}
    />
  ) : (
    <div key={index} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.html}}>
    </div>
  )
)}
```

Comment: thx for reply. After changing as you suggest, at WirisWrapper, "ref" started to come as an object with current: null. and I couldn't apply the func to dom element. Any idea?

Comment: @Er.Se Oh, do you just need to access the ref that is attached to the div (`<div ref={ref}></div>`) in `WirisWrapper`? You could probably just create the React ref locally. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox of your code for us to inspect and debug in live?